# How to install zpanel?

Tags: 12.04, server

I have bought a new server and installed Ubuntu 12.04. Now, how to install zpanel on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see this: http://forums.zpanelcp.com/showthread.php?7277-ZPX-Auto-Installer-for-Ubuntu-12-04/page3

Download auto installer and run in your Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4):

i use script to install zpanel.

Install instructions:

```
sudo su
```

(or login as root)

```
apt-get -y install tofrodos
```

Download or create ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh

```
fromdos ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh

chmod +x ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh

./ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh

shutdown -r now
```

(After AppArmor is removed)

Locate file ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh and open with text editor.

Find this and remove.

> ### disable/remove AppArmor [ -f /etc/init.d/apparmor ]
>
> ```
>     if [ $? = "0" ]; then
>
>     echo ""
>     echo -n "Stopping and Removing AppArmor: "
>
>     /etc/init.d/apparmor stop &> /dev/null
>     update-rc.d -f apparmor remove &> /dev/null
>     apt-get -y remove apparmor &> /dev/null
>     mv /etc/init.d/apparmor /etc/init.d/apparmpr.removed &> /dev/null
>
>     echo "Done."
>     echo ""
>     echo "REBOOT THE SERVER AND RUN THE SCRIPT AGAIN"
>     echo ""
>     echo ""
>     exit
>     fi
> ```

Save file and run this command.

```
./ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh
```

Reboot after installer finishes

Install post-installation patches / sql script

**File to download.**

[ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/51497732/ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh)

[post-installation patches](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/51497732/post-install_patches.zip)

Comment: .....thankyou ..& can you plz define what to do with post-installation patch ?

Comment: Paste it at /etc/zpanel/

Comment: ty & i have installed ..i have check yours & the source one both have mistake....its basically in postfix line ...check the comment of appleorange1983 @ source web

Comment: What does "download or create" mean here?

Comment: already attach link on my answer : https://dl.dropbox.com/u/51497732/ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh

Answer (score 1):

### Mistake in the script

```
dpkg -i postfix_2.9.1-4_amd64.deb postfix-mysql_2.9.1-4_amd64.deb
dpkg -i postfix_2.9.1-4_i386.deb postfix-mysql_2.9.1-4_i386.deb
```

it should be

```
dpkg -i postfix_2.9.1-5_amd64.deb postfix-mysql_2.9.1-5_amd64.deb
```

plz fix it ..its not -4 its -5

fix it if your using i386

change it in the script its on line no 192 , 193

Answer (score 1):

Though this thread is old, I wanted to contribute an updated answer as I've tested it on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS VPS (64bit). Follow below easy steps to install, but I'd suggest to have a look into below useful links before doing any changes;

- [Things to consider before installing](http://docs.zpanelcp.com/?node=7) - Explains the things to consider before installing
- [How-to answer the questionnaire which appears at installation](http://docs.zpanelcp.com/?node=51) - I've covered that part with screen shots
- [Selecting the proper php time-zone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) - Screen shots are included, but this will help you to figure-out which timezone you should select by navigating over web

---

### Installing zpanel on an Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS (x64)

Assuming that you've already logged into the server via **SSH** or direct. Below simple steps should get you going.

- Once logged in to the server; make sure you've switched to `root` user as most operation need admin privilege & also the system is up-to-date by following with an `apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get update
```

- Once updated, visit Zpanel web & [download](http://www.zpanelcp.com/download) the required package. I've used wget to download it. I've downloaded it to the root directory.

```
wget https://raw.github.com/zpanel/installers/master/install/Ubuntu-12_04/10_1_1.sh
```

As seen below, I used few commands such as `uname -a` to display system info (this may be useful to identify your OS architecture whether its 32bit or 64bit). `ls -l` to list the downloaded file(s) which is shell script `.sh` but not yet executable.

[image]

- Now lets make the file executable & install it by issuing few commands;

**Note:** According to [**this link**](http://docs.zpanelcp.com/?node=22) its says to install require package but it worked for me without installing. But its better to install to avoid any interruptions further).

- Now, assuming you're in `root` directory; (refer the image)

```
chmod +x 10_1_1.sh                # to make the file executable
ls -l                             # list down the files & check whether "x" is added
./10_1_1.sh                       # execute the script
```

[image]

- Once selecting "**y**" as seen above, set-up will prompt to select the time-zone. You may refer the links that I've mentioned at the start-up, then select the time-zone to reflect the proper time accordingly (refer below images).

[image]

[image]

[image]

- As seen above, fill-up an **FQDN** (fully qualified domain) & the respective IP in order to assign management portal by following with **y** to complete the installation. And you'll receive below screen once the installation complete. It will contain the login credentials to the zpanel admin console. It will also notify where the password file is located.

[image]

- Type **y** & enter to restart the server which will complete the installation. Below seen is the `password.txt` file & the log file which is `1800.log`. viewing the log file with `cat` will display the structure of installation which you've gone through with a quick review.

[image]

- All set now. Next is to login to the server & start managing it.

---

### Zpanel Overview (screens)

- Accessing the console using IP

[image]

- Accessing the console using FQDN

[image]

[image]

Hope this will help anyone who's searching for an updated answer to this. Any further question can be commented, I will try my best to update accordingly. :)

**Source:** [Installing & setting-up ZPanel on Ubuntu distribution](http://www.geeklk.com/2013/10/installing-setting-up-zpanel-on-an-ubuntu-distribution/)

Answer (score 0):

Take care when using ZPX_ubuntu_12-04_auto_installer.sh.
I have just run in on a Ubuntu 12.04 system and it's made a mess of the Apache2 config.  All three of the virtual web hosts I had are gone.  ie three websites are now down.  Crap.  :-(

Comment: its a clean installation script ....and i been using it from more than 1 year never broke...

Comment: All good now, it just commented out the Include sites-enabled line.  Un-commented the line and all is well again.  :-)

Now back to setting up zpanel.  I'm a zpanel newbie so wish me luck.

# Include the virtual host configurations:
Include sites-enabled/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues.